# jquery datepicker format to unix timestamp with fix hour

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, unix, datepicker

I am using a datepicker within a form which returns the date format F jS, Y (e.g. November 6th, 2013). The mysql database is set up to use Unix Timestamp which is a 10 digit format. I am now looking for a way to pass the form field value (which is November 6th, 2013) in a unix timestamp format into the database, but unfortunately it wont work.

Here is my controller code:

```
    $insertData['enddate']  = $this->input->post('openDays');
```

I tried the following:

```
    $oldenddtime = $this->input->post('openDays');
    $newenddate = int variant_date_to_timestamp ( $oldenddtime );
    $insertData['enddate']  = $newenddate;
```

The db result now is 0... Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Once this is resolved, I would need to hour within the timestamp to be ALWAYS 5pm on the selected date...

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: js timestamp is **1000 times** for unix time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)? Should do exactly what you need and convert the string to a unix timestamp.

Comment: something like that: $insertData['enddate']         = strtotime $this->input->post('openDays'); ???

Comment: More or less. Pass it your date string, get a timestamp back

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but unfortunately it only returns the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/xxx/public_html/app/controllers/project.php on line 214

Comment: Can you post the date string?